# Referencing an external parent JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am currently trying to code a GUI for an assignment as extra credit, as a learning opportunity. I need to have a menu of buttons, with each button effectively changing the main panel to enter or display data. Right now, I have a class called `buttonContainer`, which holds the main menu, and `mainPanel`, which holds the main panel for the entire GUI. Basically I need a way to have `buttonContainer` add and remove elements from its parent, `mainPanel`- with the two of them remaining seperate files.

My `buttonContainer` class looks like this:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class buttonPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private JButton load, save, list, find, input, sort, exit;
    private JPanel BtnContainer, parent;
    private newContactPanel newContact;


    public buttonPanel()
    {
        load = new JButton("Load Contacts");
        save = new JButton("Save Contacts");
        list = new JButton("List Contacts");
        find = new JButton("Find Contact");
        sort = new JButton("Sort Contacts");
        input = new JButton("New Contact");
        exit = new JButton("Exit Program");

        newContact = new newContactPanel();
        parent = this.getParent();
        BtnContainer = new JPanel();
        BtnContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
        BtnContainer.add(load);
        BtnContainer.add(save);
        BtnContainer.add(list);
        BtnContainer.add(sort);
        BtnContainer.add(find);
        BtnContainer.add(input);
        BtnContainer.add(exit);
        add(BtnContainer);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        if (e.getSource() == input)
        {
            //Change panel command here
        }

    }
}
```

With the `mainPanel` code looking like this:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class mainPanel extends JPanel //implements ActionListener
{
    private buttonPanel MainMenu;
    private newContactPanel newContact;
    private JPanel wrapper;

    public mainPanel()
    {
        wrapper = new JPanel();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        wrapper.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        MainMenu = new buttonPanel();
        newContact = new newContactPanel();

        wrapper.add(MainMenu, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(wrapper, BorderLayout.WEST);
    }
}
```

`contactPanel` is a different panel, that I want `buttonPanel` to trigger `mainPanel` to show. Is there any easy way of refrencing the parent class like this, while keeping the two classes separate?

I know variants of this question have been asked before, but, nothing I read here seemed to get done what I wanted. Several of them didn't really match exactly what I was looking for- most of them were from the same file. several used a `getParent()`- but if I try to use it, it only grabs a `Container`, and not a `JPanel`.

---

EDIT: Thanks to the people who answered. A couple of good ideas were presented- which helped me realize I forgot to actually add the action listener to the button. This question has been fully solved!

Comment: You want to keep the classes separate, but they have to access each others implementation details? Seems like a conceptual mistake at first.

Comment: i think its a force of habit. 1- I hate ungodly long files. I Like to be able to split things into smaller files, for readability. 

2. I have a tendency to go back and reuse things,so I like to keep my classes separate as much as possible, to recycle them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Basically I need a way to have buttonContainer add and remove elements from its parent, mainPanel- with the two of them remaining
>   seperate files.*

You can use [SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(class, comp)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getAncestorOfClass-java.lang.Class-java.awt.Component-) from within your `ButtonContainer` class as you know it will be a child of that class. For example:

```
class ButtonContainer extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        MainPanel mainPanel = (MainPanel)SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(MainPanel.class, ButtonContainer.this);
        if (mainPanel != null) {
            // Change panel command here
        }
    }
}
```

#### Off-topic

Please read [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) and stick to them. Class' names start with a capital letter; variables and methods names start with lower case.

Comment: thanks. ironically, because of the renames- I had to go back and change a few things. This actually lead me to find the real problem- I'm an idiot and forgot to actually add the action listener to the button. That aside, your method worked perfectly once I added the action listener- so thanks!

Comment: @Tony you are welcome! Please don't include how you solved your problem in the question (SO doesn't work like that). If someone else's answer lead you to the solution then [accept that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Or you can [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can make wrapper public static

```
public static JPanel wrapper;
```

then from buttonPanel you can use this code

```
mainPanel.wrapper.remove(<whatever component>);
mainPanel.wrapper.add(<whatever component>);
mainPanel.wrapper.validate();
mainPanel.wrapper.repaint();
```

i think this will work

Comment: While it was a good idea in theory- I added the code so just pressing the input button add the new window (a la your style), and nothing happened :/ EDIT: for clarity- by nothing happened- I mean the program compiled and ran, but pressing the button did not make the frame appear

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention you even have to resize the panel to make sure the components are visible

Comment: I did =) I maximized the program. Just for laughs, I used this to try to set the background of wrapper to green. that did not work either =)